# Как выбрать последнее значение i_id по data_id

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Есть таблица. В ней нужно выбирать все, но только последние значения i_id по data_id.

```
CREATE TABLE `dataicraci` (
`di_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`i_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`data_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `dataicraci` (`di_id`, `i_id`, `data_id`) VALUES 
(59, 6, 6), 
(62, 1, 5),
(63, 5, 5),
(64, 1, 4),
(65, 4, 4),
(66, 1, 3),
(67, 3, 3),
(68, 1, 12),
(69, 3, 12),
(70, 1, 2),
(71, 3, 2),
(96, 1, 11),
(97, 2, 11),
(102, 1, 1),
(103, 2, 1),
(106, 1, 8),
(107, 6, 8),
(110, 6, 7),
(111, 11, 7);
```

Т.е. вот эти

```
(59, 6, 6),
(63, 5, 5),
(65, 4, 4),
(67, 3, 3),
(69, 3, 12),
(71, 3, 2),
(97, 2, 11),
(103, 2, 1),
(107, 6, 8),
(111, 11, 7)
```

Можно было написать условие WHERE i_id !=1, но может быть что нету i_id равный 1 для конкретного data_id. Может быть и такое, что совпадений для конкретного data_id может быть 3 например (110, 6, 7), (111, 11, 7), (112, 12, 7). В этом случае все равно нужно брать из базы (112, 12, 7)

Comment: Используйте `group by` и вложенный запрос.

Comment: @vikolyada не могли бы вы написать? Сделал `group by` но выделяются только первые значения

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока единственное, что приходит на ум:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM dataicraci d1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(i_id) AS i_id, data_id 
    FROM dataicraci 
    GROUP BY data_id
) AS tmp
ON d1.`i_id` = tmp.i_id AND d1.`data_id` = tmp.`data_id`
```

Может быть я помешан на подзапросах и есть другие решения, а может и нет...

Comment: Благодарю ! Главное что работает